# How to make VLC visible

Tags: vlc

I started an mp3 file from Thunar, which must have triggered VLC in some way, but it is not visible, not even in the Menubar, where it often shined up as little icon and could be brought to the foreground.

It must have joined a running vlc instance, where a formerly started file had come to an end, which I found out with ps:

```
ps -C vlc 
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
21993 ?        00:12:57 vlc

ps -ax | grep vlc  
10088 pts/5    S+     0:00 grep vlc
21993 ?        Sl    12:58 /usr/bin/vlc --started-from-file /home/stefan/audio/lnp171.oga
```

Since I didn't start it from a shell, I can't do an fg command. How can I get VLC in the foreground?

Answer (score 0):

Often the easiest way around such problems is to reset the vlc settings to default. Run the following from a Terminal window:

```
vlc --reset-config
```

This may be enough to change vlc's odd behaviour...